# Why doesn't Sed remove lines at the end of a file?

Tags: bash, sed

If write like this:

```
sed '/html/d;/title/d;/body/d;/table/d' somefile.html
```

then sed deletes all occurrences, including at the end of the file, but if add this `:a;N;$!ba` then it stops deleting at the end of the file ?

```
sed '/html/d;/title/d;/body/d;/table/d
     :a;N;$!ba' somefile.html
```

This `:a;N;$!ba` is needed for further processing by regular expressions

```
cat > /dev/shm/ex01.html <<++++++++++
<html><title>Some report 01 2021 4</title><body background=White;>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<table border=1 width=90% align=center bgcolor=#f7f7e7>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
<tr><td width=80%>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
(02) some text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</td><td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
541                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
</td></tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<tr><td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
(03) some text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
</td><td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
541                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
</td></tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<tr><td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
(11) some text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
</td><td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
82                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</td></tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
</table>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
</body><html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
++++++++++

##  #1 
echo ======= 1
sed '/html/d;/title/d;/body/d;/table/d' /dev/shm/ex01.html


##  #2
echo ======= 2
sed '/html/d;/title/d;/body/d;/table/d
     :a;N;$!ba' /dev/shm/ex01.html

##  #3
echo ======= 3
echo Convert /dev/shm/ex01.html to CSV
sed '/title/d
     :a;N;$!ba
     s/ \{2,\}//g
     s#\s*</td>\s*</tr>\s*<tr>\s*<td>\s*#\n#g
     s#\s*</td>\s*<td>\s*#;#g
     s/<[^>]\+>//g
     s/\n\{2,\}//g' /dev/shm/ex01.html
```

see example at https://www.onlinegdb.com/EPB6SRJaU

I want to rewrite the last command #3

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the delete command cannot be used in the sed at the same time as concatenating the lines, then this solution, as I think, is most likely to be the most correct:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba
     s/<html.\+<table[^>]\+>//Ig
     s#\s*</td>\s*</tr>\s*<tr>\s*<td>\s*#\n#Ig
     s#\s*</td>\s*<td>\s*#;#Ig
     s/<[^>]\+>//g;s/\s\{2,\}//g' report.html
```

see https://onlinegdb.com/BGAhn3c8U